# Error while creating a model in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am currently reading [The definitive guide to Django](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter05.html), and came across an unexpected error. I set my database as sqlite3 and tested it. So far so good.

First, I created the an app with the following command,

```
python manage.py startapp books
```

Then I created the corresponding  model

from django.db import models

```
class Publisher(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    state_province = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    website = models.URLField()

class Author(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    email = models.EmailField()

class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author)
    publisher = models.ForeignKey(Publisher)
    publication_date = models.DateField()
```

I can successfully  validate it,

```
python manage.py validate
```

but when I try to print out the corresponding SQL commands with,

```
 python manage.py sqlall books
```

I get the following error:

```
django.db.utils.DatabaseError: file is encrypted or is not a database
```

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance

My settings are:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': '/home/******/mysite/mysite/data/test.db',
        'USER': '',                      # Not used with sqlite3.
        'PASSWORD': '',                  # Not used with sqlite3.
        'HOST': '',                      
        'PORT': '',
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you ran `python manage.py syncdb` to create the database and all the tables/models?

Comment: yes, and I get the very same error

Comment: Can you post the `DATABASES` dict from your `settings.py`?

Comment: And you've confirmed that the full path exists and `test.db` file exists? It probably won't be there if `syncdb` is failing. Does the user running `syncdb` have write access to the directory? If you drop into a python shell can you run `import sqlite3` successfully?

Comment: great suggestion Scott. The access rights are OK. Now, I deleted it and created one programatically with the sqlite3 module. And that worked. The previous one I created it from the sqlite3 prompt. I'll check out what the differences are, but so far, my problem is fixed. Thanks!